# Azure synapse get metadata

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to get a list of all files in a folder with get metadata activity. To pass this list to the for-each activity, which in turn executes a notebook.

I have a binary dataset and field list is set to child items.

Pipeline crashes every time with the error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2011",
    "message": "Blob operation Failed. ContainerName: tmp, path: /tmp/folder/folder1/.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Get Metadata",
    "details": []
}
```

The files are in 'folder/folder1'.

It's not my first time working with Get Metadata activity and so far it has always worked (in ADF). But I do it first time in Synapse, are there differences? Do you have any ideas what this could be or how I can solve the problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/471434/getting-below-error-while-running-a-copy-data-acti.html

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7e2c7388-7981-4d86-8589-4e7762a99af1/metadata-activity-cant-connect-to-blob-storage?forum=AzureDataFactory

Comment: We use this pattern a lot, and it definitely works. Can you show the GetMetadata and Dataset configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `Get Metadata` activity to retrieve the metadata of any data is the same in the **Azure data factory** and **Azure Synapse pipeline**.

1. Create a **binary** dataset with a dataset parameter for filename.

[image]

2. Connect the binary dataset to the Get metadata activity.

- Pass **'*'** to the filename parameter value.
- Select **child items** under Field list to get the list of files/subfolders from the folder.

[image]

3. The **output** gives the list of files from the folder.

[image]